# Is the optimal objective of a linear program continuous in its right-hand-side?

Tags: linear-programming

Consider a linear program 
$$f(b)=\min_{x}\{c^\top x: A x = b, x\geq 0\}$$
(assume it is feasible and bounded for all $b$). My understanding is that $f(b)$ is a convex piecewise linear function of $b$ (can be shown taking the dual of the LP, see below).

### **My question**

Can I also say that $f(b)$ is continuous? Or when can I say that?

Below my attempts to workout a proof, though I strongly believe someone has done that already.

---

### **Proof that $f(b)$ is convex and piecewise linear**

By strong duality
$$f(b)=\min_{x}\{c^\top x: A x = b, x\geq 0\}=\max_\pi\{\pi b:\pi A\leq c\}$$
If we let $\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_K$ be the extreme points of $\{\pi A\leq c\}$ we can rewrite the dual as 
$$f(b)=\max_{\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_K}\{\pi_i b\}$$
This gives us a piecewise linear function in $b$. Furthermore, the pointwise max of a set of linear functions is convex, hence $f(b)$ is convex and piecewise linear in $b$.

---

### **Working out a proof**

Assume we take $b\in B$ where $B$, loosely speaking is the set of vectors $b$ for which the linear program has a finite optimal solution, i.e. $f(b)$ is defined.

Now, since linear functions are continuous, if the pointwise maximum of continuous functions is continuous the proof is done (but I do not know if that holds). I will try in another way:

Take a sequence $(b_n)$ converging to $b_0$ (assume $B$ is closed). I need to show that $\lim f(b_n)=f(b_0)$
$$\begin{align}
\lim f(b_n) =& \lim\max_{\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_K}\{\pi_i b_n\}\\
=&\max_{\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_K}\{\lim\pi_i b_n\}\\
=&\max_{\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_K}\{\pi_i\lim b_n\}\\
=&\max_{\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_K}\{\pi_i b_0\}\\
=&f(b_0)
\end{align}$$
Hence $f(b)$ is continuous. But I am walking on thin ice when I say that the limit of the maximum is equal to the maximum of the limit (second line).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the linear program is feasible and bounded for all $b$, then $f(b)$ is finite, i.e. $-\infty < f(b) < +\infty$ for all $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$. By strong duality, $f(b)$ is also convex, as you have shown.

It is a classical result that all convex functions finite on $\mathbb{R}^m$ are continuous. See for example the book *Convex Analysis* by Rockafellar, Corollary 10.1.1. To demonstrate the usefulness of the corollary, an example about the pointwise supremum of convex functions is given, which is very similar to your question.

Things might be a little bit more complicated if there exist $b$ such that $f(b) \in \{-\infty,+\infty\}$, but for this case, *Convex Analysis* should also be a good resource.

*Rockafellar, R. T. (1970). Convex analysis (No. 28). Princeton university press.*